# CSC : error CS2001: Source file '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78.AssemblyAttributes.cs' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, bamboo

When start build on my **Bamboo** server ,I am getting following error:

> Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn
>   CSC : error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78.AssemblyAttributes.cs' could not be found. [E:\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\Domain\Domain.csproj]
>   Done Building Project "E:\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\Business\Business.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Unable to understand this error. On Local this works perfect even on command line - `MSBuild`command.

Comment: any update for this issue? AFAIK, The error CS2001 indicates it could not generate temporary class. This is probably because the building account lost permission to the C:\Windows\system32 folder, Have you try to grant all permission to your account, including read/write/full control?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your build service is running as a system account (e.g. local system, network service, etc.) which leads to undesired behaviour in msbuild.

You should create a dedicated service user and configure the service to run as this user or ensure that the service user has sufficient rights to modify the system profile directory (which I don't recommend).

You can follow [Atlassian's guide on how to run the windows service as a local user](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/running-bamboo-as-a-windows-service-as-the-local-user-416580754.html).